# Using encapsulation getter in methods of the same class

Tags: java, encapsulation, setter, getter

I am following a course on Java and a solution to a possible exam question states the following (in a class called Parcel):

```
private boolean international;
private double weight;

public Parcel(boolean international, double weight){
    // It is important to also use encapsulation in the constructor. Here we force all
    // variable access through the setter methods. In our example this makes sure that
    // all parcels have a negative weight. If later modifications are made to what values
    // are acceptable, we only need to change the accessor methods, instead of all pieces of code
    // that modify the variable.
    this.setInternational(international);
    this.setWeight(weight);
}

public double getShippingPrice(){
    // Also in this case it is recommended to use the accessor method instead of directly accessing the variable
    if(this.isInternational()){
        return (15 + 7*this.getWeight());
    } else {
        return (5 + 4*this.getWeight());
    }
}
public boolean isInternational(){
    return this.international;
}

public void setInternational(boolean international){
    this.international = international;
}

public double getWeight(){
    return this.weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight){
    if(weight >= 0){
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A package cannot have a negative weight");
    }
}
```

I understand why encapsulation is useful for international: by doing so, we make sure that the given values are the ones we want and throw exceptions where needed. However, I do not understand why you would need such a way of working in get `getShippingPrice()` method. Why do you need the getter `isInternational`, and why not use `international`? What is the advantage of using getters and setters in the same class they are written in? The latter I have already answered, at least partially: it gives you more control over the input. But why use getters?

Comment: The visibility of fields can be `private`, `protected`, `default` (or package visible) and `public`. If you make your fields private, because you want to use setters, then you need getters, because they are still private. This is one reason, but in general you want to separate the interface from the implementation, you don't want to show actually that you have a field called `international`, and clients of your class should not bother indeed about the implementation. So, my conclusion is that getters serve as an abstraction.

Comment: @nbro I understand that, but I do not understand in this specific case why you use a getter *in the same class* as the field. The field is private, so it is still visible in this class. So why would you need the getter?

Comment: The getter is of course useful for external classes and not for the methods in the same class (in general). Of course the getter could also be useful in other methods of the same class, if that getter does some special work, which is not the case.

Comment: @nbro So I am right in thinking that there is no advantage in using the getter in this case, as we're still in the same class and the getter doesn't do anything special such as Andremoniy's answer would imply? In this case there is no advantage? It is the comment that confused me *Also in this case it is recommended to use the accessor method instead of directly accessing the variable*. I don't see why.

Comment: From my experience, if the getter only returns the value of the variable, then it is not useful inside the class, unless you want to have abstractions also for those programmers that maintain your code (and for you). Of course, in the future, if you wanted to change the way your getter works internally, then you might choose to use getters also inside your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two cases.

First one is that you can override these getters in future class successors, so these getters could have another implementation.

Another case, some special logic inside getters, for example `null` fields can obtain initial values. This method is often used for getters of collection fields in auto-generated `JAXB`-annotated beans:

```
public List<String> getList() {
    if (this.list == null) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return this.list;
}
```

Comment: I understand that, some form of lazy instantiation I guess. But that does not explain why a getter is used in the code I gave. There is no such thing happening there.

Answer (score 0):

It's ofcourse not useful for accessing it within the class as you would directly use `international` private field.

But think of the consumer's of this `parcel` object. Assume post office needs to decide whether it's needs to be shipped to international location or to a domestic location. In order for post office to make a distinction, it can't directly access parcel's private field and hence would make a `isInternational` call and hence you have getter method in your `Parcel` class.

Comment: I understad, that is not my question. Why did the professor giving this course comment that we should use the getter inside the getshippingprice even though that method is inside the same class as the private field?

Comment: That's how postoffice would price its customer based on whether parcel is internation or not.

Comment: You don't understand. I get why getters and setters are necessary. But not why in this specific case you would use isInternational inside a method that is in the same class as the private field. The field is accessible by the method anyway, you don't need the getter.